# Implicit declaration of function con inicialización de structs, en C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de inicializar unos structs y dentro de otros structs y me salta este error: [image: MENSAJE DE ERROR]

¿Por qué pasa esto? Dentro del procedimiento de la línea 5 yo llamo a mi otro procedimiento que por separado me inicializa SOLO los personajes, dentro de la invocación hago `juego->personajes[MAX_PERSONAJES], juego->tope_personajes` para hacer referencia a el tipo de dato *personaje_t* e *int*, porque en la función de la línea 10 pido como parámetros de ese tipo.

Código a continuación:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "kronos.h"
void inicializar_juego (juego_t* juego){
    inicializar_personajes(juego->personajes[MAX_PERSONAJES], juego->tope_personajes);

}

void inicializar_personajes(personaje_t personajes[MAX_PERSONAJES], int tope_personajes){
    personajes[0].posicion.fila = -1;
    personajes[0].posicion.columna =-1;
    personajes[0].movimientos = 25;
    personajes[0].movimientos_con_poder = 22;
    personajes[0].cuadrante_inicial = 1;
    personajes[0].posicion.fila  = (rand() % (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    personajes[0].posicion.columna  = (rand() % (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    

    personajes[1].posicion.fila = -1;
    personajes[1].posicion.columna =-1;
    personajes[1].movimientos = 30;
    personajes[1].movimientos_con_poder = 22;
    personajes[1].cuadrante_inicial = 2;
    personajes[1].posicion.fila  = (rand() % (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    personajes[1].posicion.columna  = (rand() % (19 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
    

    personajes[2].posicion.fila = -1;
    personajes[2].posicion.columna =-1;
    personajes[2].movimientos = 20;
    personajes[2].movimientos_con_poder = 22;
    personajes[2].cuadrante_inicial = 3;
    personajes[2].posicion.fila  = (rand() % (19 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
    personajes[2].posicion.columna  = (rand() % (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    

    personajes[3].posicion.fila = -1;
    personajes[3].posicion.columna =-1;
    personajes[3].movimientos = 15;
    personajes[3].movimientos_con_poder = 22;
    personajes[3].cuadrante_inicial = 4;

    personajes[3].posicion.fila  = (rand() % (19 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
    personajes[3].posicion.columna  = (rand() % (19 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
}
```

Y este sería el .h que incluyo en el código anterior con los structs que utilizo:

```
#ifndef __KRONOS_H__
#define __KRONOS_H__
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_LASERS 100
#define MAX_ROBOTS 10
#define MAX_PERSONAJES 10
#define MAX_PINZAS 100
#define MAX_SUPERTRAJES 10
const char ELASTIC = 'E';
const char VIOLETA = 'A';
const char DASH = 'D';
const char MR_INCREIBLE = 'M';

typedef struct coordenada{
    int fila;
    int columna;
} coordenada_t; 

typedef struct robot{
    coordenada_t posicion;
    coordenada_t lasers[MAX_LASERS];
    int tope_lasers;

} robot_t;

typedef struct supertraje{
    coordenada_t posicion;
    int cuadrante;
    bool recolectado;
    bool usado;
} supertraje_t;

typedef struct personaje{
    bool poder_activado;
    bool tiene_supertraje;
    coordenada_t posicion;
    int movimientos;
    int movimientos_con_poder;
    int cuadrante_inicial;
} personaje_t;

typedef struct juego{
    personaje_t personajes [MAX_PERSONAJES];
    int tope_personajes;
    robot_t robots [MAX_ROBOTS];
    int tope_robots;
    coordenada_t pinzas [MAX_PINZAS];
    int tope_pinzas;
    supertraje_t supertrajes [MAX_SUPERTRAJES];
    int tope_supertraje;
    int longitud_laser;
    int id_personaje_actual;
} juego_t;

/* Inicializa el jego, cargando toda la informacion inicial de los robots,
los supertrajes, el personaje, los lasers y las pinzas.
EL campo id_personaje_actual comienza en 1.
*/
void inicializar_juego (juego_t* juego);

/* Movera el personaje y se realizaran todas las acciones necesarias en caso
de chocar con algun elemento.
*/
void realizar_jugada (juego_t* juego, char movimiento);

/* Imprime el juego por pantalla
*/
void imprimir_terreno (juego_t juego);

/*EL juego se dara por ganado si se esta sobre el casillero de salida siendo el
personaje Mr. Increible y perdido si el personaje (cualquiera) se queda sin movimivientos.
Devuelve:
-> 1 si se gano el juego
-> 0 si el juego aun se esta jugando
-> -1 si se perdio el juego.
*/
int estado_juego(juego_t juego);

#endif /* __KRONOS_H__ */
```

Answer (score 0):

El primero error se debe a que la función `inicializar_juego` no sabe que existe la función `inicializar_personajes`. Porque está después.

Quizá te olvidaste de agregar la declaración al archivo .h:

```
void inicializar_juego (juego_t* juego);
```

Con la función [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) sucede algo muy parecido. Tienes que escribir una declaración o agregar `#include <stdlib.h>`.

---

El segundo error ocurre porque los tipos no coinciden.

La función `inicializar_personajes` espera un arreglo, pero recibe el elemento en la posición `MAX_PERSONAJES` del arreglo `personajes`:

```
inicializar_personajes(juego->personajes[MAX_PERSONAJES]);
```

Debería ser simplemente:

```
inicializar_personajes(juego->personajes);
```

Ten en cuenta que aunque una variable se declare con [`[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Subscript) o [`*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Dereference), para hacer referencia a una variable solo usas su nombre. Porque fuera de una declaración, esos símbolos son operadores.